# Delete Excel Pivot Table Timeline Slicer

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that works to delete all pivot table slicers off a particular sheet. When it comes to a timeline slicer (xltimeline) though, it doesn't delete it.

```
For Each Shape In Worksheets(SheetName).Shapes
    If Shape.Type = msoSlicer Then Shape.Delete
Next Shape
```

Any thoughts on why it won't recognize the timeline slicer as a msoSlicer and delete it? I am not sure what to classify the timeline as if it isn't msoSlicer.

Comment: Can you check the `Shape.Type` on that specific shape using `Debug.Print Shape.Type` and let me know if it actually is `msoSlicer`?

Comment: as per my understanding, the timeline is of type msoShapeTypeMixed

Comment: @JvdV it returns -2 as the shape.type

Comment: Well there you go, that value means it's indeed a msoShapeTypeMixed type, hence why it won't delete. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.msoshapetype)

Comment: Thank you both for your help! That worked!

Comment: @JvdV  Do you think you might be able to help with this problem? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55735045/adding-pivot-tables-to-slicer)

Comment: @RicardoDiaz See comment above ^